# cannot run executable made by nasm in windows 7

Tags: assembly, nasm

i am using windows 7 for learning assembly language.I am using NASM for creating object files and mingw for creating executable files.

i am using the following commands for compile and run executable files

```
del hello.o
del hello.exe
nasm -f elf hello.asm
ld hello.o -o hello.exe
hello
```

while running the hello.exe file,an error message showing "hello.exe has stoped working"

while using the following command

```
    nasm -f bin hello.asm -o program.exe
```

i have got an error shown below

[image]

my program code

```
global _start            ; global entry point export for ld
section .text
_start:
; sys_write(stdout, message, length)
mov eax, 4        ; sys_write syscall
mov ebx, 1        ; stdout
mov ecx, message    ; message address
mov edx, length        ; message string length
int 80h
; sys_exit(return_code)
mov eax, 1        ; sys_exit syscall
mov ebx, 0        ; return 0 (success)
int 80h
section .data
message: db 'Hello, world!',0x0A    ; message and newline
length: equ $-message            ; NASM definition pseudo-instruction
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is *Linux* code (`int 0x80`, `sys_write` and `sys_exit` being kernel system calls for rather low-level stuff).

I'm not convinced it's a good idea to try and call the Linux kernel when you're running on the Windows operating system. That's unlikely to end well :-)

MinGW is minimalist GNU for *Windows,* a way of using the `gcc` toolchain for writing Windows applications. You have to therefore follow the Windows rules.

Comment: how to compile 8086 program using nasm

Comment: You're _compiling_ (assembling, technically) it correctly other than the options. I don't think you want to use ELF format (since that's not the way Windows does things), or BIN format (since that's flat file (like the ancient COM files), not EXE format). Your problem is not so much the compilation _process_ but the source code you're compiling. You need to write code that can talk to the Windows OS, not the Linux one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572818/best-book-to-learn-windows-assembly-programming for example.

Comment: @mcandre, you have to find the equivalent Windows methods and call _them._

Comment: @paxdiablo, could you help me identify these? Assembler tutorials are few and far between, especially for specific platforms, or worse, multiplatform.

Comment: @mcandre, the first, `sys_write` with file descriptor 1, is simply sending something to standard output. The second, `sys_exit` is exiting the program. For Windows (in console mode), I'd be looking at `GetStdHandle/WriteConsoleA` and `ExitProcess`. But this really should be asked as a separate question so you get a wider range of answers.

Answer (score 2):

Besides your code calling the linux kernel, as paxdiablo pointed out, you have assembled it to  flat-form binary, which will not run under windows. You need to use `nasm -f win32`.

Comment: how to compile 8086 program using nasm