# x86 assembly create Win32 executable NASM

Tags: winapi, assembly, nasm

I want to create a valid Win32 executable, that can be run as standalone application.

For example, this simple program:

```
bits 32
mov eax,1
ret
```

I compiled it using NASM with

```
nasm test.asm -o test.exe
```

Then I ran that program.
It started NTVDM and it told me *"The NTVDM CPU encountered illegal instruction"* and some technical details, probably dump, and registers.

So, I want to create a standalone Win32 application in assembly language. I don't want to create COM file, like in DOS.

Comment: You probably need to read [Iczelion's Win32 Assembly](http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/tutorials.html) tutorials. To solve you specific problem you need a linker that is capable of producing a PE image.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembler-under-windows

Comment: Have you tried to select an output format, suitable for your operating system ?
eg. `-f win32` switch to create a linkable object file for Windows.

Comment: And yet another example: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmexamples/

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot run executable made by nasm in windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477818/cannot-run-executable-made-by-nasm-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[section] .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 1
    ret
```

can be assembled like this:

```
 nasm -fwin32 file.asm              (this should give you file.obj)
```

and

```
 link /subsystem:windows /entry:start file.obj
```

(or)

```
 ld -e _start file.obj
```

whatever linker you choose should give you your .exe

Answer (score 0):

At least Windows XP refuses to load an application that does not use any DLL files. I didn't test with Windows 7 up to now!

The reason is that there are no official interfaces but the DLLs that come with Windows and that a program that has neither inputs nor outputs makes no sense.