# Displaying text in command line after executing a .exe file from a compiled .asm file

Tags: assembly, gcc, command-line, mingw, nasm

This might be a dumb question but I'm new to assembly programming and I've converted a `.asm` file containing the following assembly source code to a `.exe` file. The code was taken from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_memory_management.htm by the way.

```
section .text
   global _main         ;must be declared for using gcc
    
_main:                   ;tell linker entry point

   mov  eax, 45      ;sys_brk
   xor  ebx, ebx
   int  80h

   add  eax, 16384   ;number of bytes to be reserved
   mov  ebx, eax
   mov  eax, 45      ;sys_brk
   int  80h
    
   cmp  eax, 0
   jl   exit    ;exit, if error 
   mov  edi, eax     ;EDI = highest available address
   sub  edi, 4       ;pointing to the last DWORD  
   mov  ecx, 4096    ;number of DWORDs allocated
   xor  eax, eax     ;clear eax
   std           ;backward
   rep  stosd            ;repete for entire allocated area
   cld           ;put DF flag to normal state
    
   mov  eax, 4
   mov  ebx, 1
   mov  ecx, msg
   mov  edx, len
   int  80h      ;print a message

exit:
   mov  eax, 1
   xor  ebx, ebx
   int  80h
    
section .data
msg     db  "Allocated 16 kb of memory!", 10
len     equ $ - msg
```

I then ran the following codes in the command line and got no confirmation output:
[command line NASM and GCC commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4wSt.png)

If I run it in an online compiler, I'm getting a confirmation message "Allocated 16 kb of memory!", whereas no message was prompted in the command line. Am I missing something? or what should I add. How will a know if 16kb was allocated? I've fiddled with this previous query but I still don't know how: [Create an exe file in assembly with NASM on 32-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407363/create-an-exe-file-in-assembly-with-nasm-on-32-bit-windows). I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Those `int 80h` instructions are Linux system calls.  They won't work in a native Windows .exe, just fault like `int 123` or any other interrupt number that Windows doesn't set up for user-space to use.  I doubt Windows even has a `brk` at all; call VirtualAlloc instead.  I assume the online "compiler" you used was running it on a Linux server.  Assembly language programs are not portable between OSes, *at all*.  Only the pure computation part, not the OS interaction.

Comment: The comments on [Create an exe file in assembly with NASM on 32-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37407363) already explain this, and so does one of the answers.  The accepted answer replaces the system calls with library function calls.

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion and ran it in an Ubuntu cmd I downloaded from microsoft store and followed all the protocols to make it work. used `nasm -f elf64 file.asm` and `ld -s -o test test.o` but I get the error **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** Am I missing something?

Comment: That's 32-bit code dealing with pointers. 
 Besides the system-call issue ([What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46087731)), you'd be truncating 64-bit pointers to 32-bit if the system calls succeed.  Of if it's WSL1, then `int 80h` itself will segfault.  If you want to write x86-64 Linux code, use different registers and call numbers for the `syscall` instruction.  Actually I suspect the latter, so even `nasm -felf32 test.asm` / `ld -m elf_i386 test.o` wouldn't help.  Even in a 64-bit executable, a non-PIE would have a low-32 brk.

Comment: I'm really lost, I've tried researching and encountered these queries https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268319/ubuntu-18-04-lts-64-bit-issues-running-32-bit-execute-file-have-followed-previo but I still encounter installation errors. How do you think should I proceed? Thanks for the help btw. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're using WSL, see [Does WSL 2 really support 32 bit program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61300194) to make sure your VM is actually WSL2, which is necessary running 32-bit programs.  For this program specifically, you're not even using libc, so truly just NASM and `ld` are necessary.  Packages like `gcc-multilib` are irrelevant, the only thing that matters is kernel support for CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION to run a 32-bit static executable.  `nasm` always supports `-felf32`, and a 64-bit build of `ld` always supports `-m elf_i386` to make 32-bit executables.